# Cannot change the color of this block in forums (CSS)

Tags: css, ipb

I've been working on recoloring a theme.

I have on IPB I've been changing everything from white to a grey, but this one part.

Gyazo attached with a sample of a post where the white is below the `userblock`. How can I possibly change this to match the post block?

https://gyazo.com/dfd7be2cbfd0bed5fa7544dbdb33ec78

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using chrome

1. right-click the white area
2. click inspect element
3. go to the elements tab if you are not there yet
4. look to the right side of that window
5. figure out where its being colored white
6. click the link on top right of the selector
7. voila.. you see the line of css in your css file that you need to change

you may want to check out this: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

opera has the same functionality since its built on top of chromium.

firefox has something similar but google it yourself.

IE.. don't even think about it.

Comment: I appreciate the help, and this is how i found how to change everything else, however this margin/border/padding whatever it is has no color defined in this section it brings up :/

Comment: if you take a look below the html structure in that elements tab, you'd find a small strip that goes like: `html body div something else table bla bla` and so on. you'd need to click the second one from right and see if the color is there. if you can't find it, choose the next element and so on.